# why plugins are loaded prior to pluggables

Tags: plugins, pluggable

[image: WP URL call]

I got this image from one E-book for WP plugin development. Could you please clarify me why the Plugins are loaded before Pluggables.

Comment: Please watch the license. Every content in here is GNU GPL licensed. If the image isn't, then please remove it and replace it with your own. Else the sky might fall on your head.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly from source for [`pluggable.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/pluggable.php):

```
<?php
/**
 * These functions can be replaced via plugins. If plugins do not redefine these
 * functions, then these will be used instead.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */
?>
```

So, there's your answer, the functions in `pluggable.php` are **intended to be overridden by Plugins**.

Re: load order:

See [this post by Konstantin Kovshenin](http://theme.fm/2011/09/wordpress-internals-how-wordpress-boots-up-part-2-2437/). The relevant points (10-15):

> 1. **`wp_get_active_and_valid_plugins()` retrieves the list of all active plugin files for loading and includes them. This is the point where your plugin code gets executed, functions, classes defined, etc.**
> 2. **Includes `wp-includes/wp-pluggable.php` and `wp-includes/wp-pluggable-deprecated.php`** which include functions (and deprecated functions) that can be redefined by plugins. Like `wp_mail()` for more advanced mailing, `wp_authenticate()` for alternative authentication methods, etc.
> 3. `wp_set_internal_encoding()` is called to set the internal encoding according to the blog_charset option.
> 4. `wp_cache_postload()` is called if object caching is enabled.
> 5. **At this point a `plugins_loaded` action is fired.** This is the very first action (after muplugins_loaded fired before loading the non-multi-site WordPress plugins) that you can hook into, it comes before the init because WordPress has not been initialized yet, at least not fully.

So, simplified:

1. Plugins are loaded
2. `pluggable.php` is loaded
3. `plugins_loaded` action is fired

Which is the expected order.

(Note: this all takes place in [`wp-settings.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-settings.php).)

Comment: The doubt is, as you said if the functions of pluggable.php is overridden by plugin means the pluggable.php should have been loaded prior to plugins. But the Diagram link shows in reverse order.

Comment: The order takes place as expected. See updated answer.

Comment: Each function definition in `pluggables` is preceded with an `if(!function_exists('{function name}') {` check.  WordPress checks to see if you've manually defined any of these functions in your own plugins *before* defining them on its own.

Comment: @EAMann Thank you  EAMann, Now I'm very clear about my question now that, example, if the plugin defines the function `wp_set_current_user`, then in pluggable.php, `wp_set_current_user` won't be defined as `if ( !function_exists('wp_set_current_user') ) :`, Am I right ?

Comment: You are right. If you define the function in your own plugin, WordPress will use *your version* instead of the one in `pluggables.php`.

Answer (score 0):

## Don't use pluggable functions!

Please note that you can **never be sure, that a later plugin doesn't override your pluggable**! I wrote on [wp-hackers mailing list about this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wp-hackers/-EJbmkdMLjg) some time ago.

There's also [another thread on wp-hackers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wp-hackers/MSlfg6E9wCU) that talks about that there's no fallback implemented. Please [also read the related trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/8833).