# Custom login form redirect to external site

Tags: redirect, login, wp-login-form

I created a private page, but this page needs to be more than just available by entering a code for a page that has been listed private in the Publish settings of Visibility, so I created a page and have added an if/else statement to check if the user is logged in or not.  If so, the content displays as it should, if they aren't the login form appears and the user is prompted to login which appears as it should.

The problem is, after they login using the form they are redirected to the admin page.  I have added a redirect to the login page to go to the page I want but it doesn't seem to work.  Am I doing the redirect incorrectly?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Minutes
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'nav' ); ?>  
<?php get_template_part( 'templates/content', 'breadcrumb' ); ?> 




<section class="band bottom u-full-width" style="margin-top: 2%">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">


<?php if (is_user_logged_in()) { ?>


<div class="ten columns" >

<h5><b>Click the Plus (+) Sign to expend the list of available minutes per section</b></h5>   

Plus more code


<?php } else {
    echo 'We are sorry, but this area is only for registered, logged in users. If you are a registered user, please use the link below to login to the site to view content not available to the general public.  If you have any questions, please contact us.';
    wp_login_form(array('redirect' => 'http://etomv2.bambergmarketing.com/meeting-minutes'));
}
?>

</div>

</div></div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you tested in a vanilla WordPress install? All too often I see a plugin/theme hijacking the login redirect with complete disregard for anything other than its own intentions.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by vanilla?  I've tested this on two domains with same result, it goes to the admin page and not my redirected page.

Comment: As in a plain install. No plugins. Default theme. Put it this way, I just tested the `redirect` param with `wp_login_form` on a "vanilla" install and it works exactly as expected - thus it must be a rogue plugin and/or your theme. The only way to find the culprit is disable all of them, then one by one re-activate and test until it stops working again!

Comment: I understand.  It must be in my theme, I tried disabling all my plugins and  still having an issue. Any ideas where I might look in my theme to try and fix it?  Thank you @TheDeadMedic

Comment: MY BAD! I started doubting myself, so I tested again - the redirect **won't** work if the URL is to another domain! (you can only redirect back to anywhere on your site).

Comment: This is due to `wp_safe_redirect` in `wp-login.php:840`

Answer (score 6):

### Internal happenings explained

When you look at [`wp_login_form()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_form/), then you will see, that the `redirect` argument will ask for an absolute URl. So either use `admin_url()` or `site_url()` if you want to link *internally*.

The `action`/ target of this form is not meant to be changed (unless you set `echo` to `FALSE` and use some `\DOMDocument` replacement or some Regex to change it in the output string):

```
action="' . esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ) . '" method="post"
```

When you then look at [`wp_login.php` and the `case : 'login'`|`default`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/708b9dc229e8bfaa90c2eb59709da8ef007dbf84/wp-login.php#L758-L848), you will note two things:

1. There's [a filter](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/708b9dc229e8bfaa90c2eb59709da8ef007dbf84/wp-login.php#L816) to adjust the redirect, which might override anything set in your arguments. Keep in mind that this might even switch depending on the user who performs the login action (typically used to redirect users of different roles to different welcome screens):

   ```
   apply_filters( 'login_redirect', $redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user );
   ```
2. Then the user gets checked if it is authenticated and not an erroneous object. Depending on that, if the request is not directed at the `/wp-admin` side of things, the following function is called:

   ```
   exit( wp_safe_redirect( $target ) );
   ```

…and using [`wp_safe_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_safe_redirect/) means that you can **not** link outside (figured that from @TheDeadMedic comment – thanks!).

## Solutions

As usual in WordPress, you have options:

1. This function is inside [`pluggable.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/708b9dc229e8bfaa90c2eb59709da8ef007dbf84/wp-includes/pluggable.php), which means you can replace it with your **own** function. This is not very stable (every other plugin can do the same), but it's ok if you use it on your personal site, document this is in place and fix things when there's a conflict. [More info in this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/39232/385) and the answer by @ChipBennet on it.
2. The **better solution** is to look at [`wp_validate_redirect()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_validate_redirect/) which is internally used by `wp_safe_redirect()` and leverage the filter that WP offers to **extend the list of allowed hosts**.

   ```
   // End of `wp_validate_redirect()`
   $allowed_hosts = (array) apply_filters( 
       'allowed_redirect_hosts', 
       array( $wpp['host'] ), 
       isset( $lp['host'] ) ? $lp['host'] : '' 
   );

   if ( 
       isset($lp['host']) 
       && ( !in_array($lp['host'], $allowed_hosts) 
       && $lp['host'] != strtolower($wpp['host'])) 
   )
       $location = $default;
   ```

   In your case a (mu-)plugin to allow that redirect would look like the following:

   ```
   <?php /* Plugin Name: Allow external login redirect */
   add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts', function( Array $hosts, $check )
   {
       return $hosts + [ 'http://etomv2.bambergmarketing.com' ];
   }, 10, 2 );
   ```

   Also take a look at the second argument inside `wp_safe_redirect( $target, $fallback )` that is used for `wp_validate_redirect()`. It is set as filter. That means, that you can redirect to another external URl in case your login fails. Or you can redirect locally to some error page (or just the current page, which is the default):

   ```
   apply_filters( 'wp_safe_redirect_fallback', admin_url(), $status )
   ```

The second solution is what I would use. You might also want to use it in case you are using some external OAuth provider that you need to validate users against.

### Note

In case you read the docs and wonder about `login_post` as "scheme" in there: The `site_url()` function is a wrapper for [`get_site_url()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_site_url/) which uses [`set_url_scheme()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/set_url_scheme/) internally. There `login_post`, `login` and `rpc` are equal to `admin`, which adjusts the action properly:

```
$scheme = is_ssl() || force_ssl_admin() ? 'https' : 'http';
```

Comment: I had to remove the protocol (e.g., `https://`) when adding hosts to the filter `allowed_redirect_hosts`.